# ajax & PDO variable as condition for WHERE

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, pdo

So i wanted to make a little "search engine" for my database.
my javascript is:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#display").click(function () {
         var zoeknaam = $("#zoeknaam").val();
         var zoektype = $("#zoektype").text();
         $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
             type: "POST",
             url: "display.php",
             data: { name: zoeknaam, zoekt: "name" },
             dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
             success: function (response) {
                 $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
                 //alert(response);
             }

         });
     });
 });
```

my html is the following:

```
<input type="text" name="inputtext" id="zoeknaam" />
<select name="searchtype" id="zoektype"><option value="name">name</option><option value="age">age</option></select>
<input type="button" id="display" value="Display All Data" />
```

and now i have my php

```
include("connection.php");
$dataget = $_POST["name"];
$datawaar = $_POST["zoekt"];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM student WHERE :waar=:postname");
$stmt->bindParam(':waar', $datawaar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':postname', $dataget, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
echo "<table>";
while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[name]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[address]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[age]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

When i remove the where condition and set the condition to name it works. Now when i retrieve it with the post and param it doesn't work.
The connection.php is correct since it works with the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
... WHERE :waar=:postname
```

You can only bind values using placeholders in a prepared statement, not column- or table names.

If you want to accept and use client-provided column- or table names, the only way to secure that, is to check them against a white-list and then inject them directly in the query string.

Comment: I do know how to secure it agains sql injections but why isn't the statement working with :waar as where condition and :postname as value
since if waar = name and postname test the statement would have WHERE name="test" which should work

Comment: @emielpopelier That is by design. As fas as I know, it is mainly because the sql engine cannot prepare anything when the table- and / or column names are unknown at the time of preparing: It doesn't know which indices to use, how to optimize the query, etc. etc. So there is really nothing to prepare. Sql injection security is just a nice side-effect of that.

Comment: i tried to change the prepare into query but that didn't give any result either. Is there something else in stead of the ->prepare ?

Comment: @emielpopelier I'm not sure what you have changed, but the bottom line is that you can only use place-holders for *values*, not for column- or table names (or operators, etc.).

Comment: Well I guess i don't need the prepared then but what do i need then? Do i need $conn->query("SELECT * FROM studend WHERE :waar=:postname") ? Since this didn't work either

Comment: @emielpopelier You need something like `... WHERE $column_name = :postname` where `$column_name` is the POST value that has been checked against a white-list. And you still need the prepared statement for the `:postname` value / placeholder.

Comment: But does it work $column_name in the statement? Since i thought it isnt working if i put a php value in the prepare statement?